# Adding slave device to Arduino Uno-SPI | Configuring pins

Tags: arduino-uno, pins, spi

I recently started an oled project. I use a small "128X64 OLED LCD LED Display Module" and I control it using SPI protocol(with my Arduino).

It is the only device connected to the microcontroller. But I have some questions regarding the pins. I found [this](https://learn.adafruit.com/monochrome-oled-breakouts/wiring-1-dot-3-128x64) tutorial and it uses pins 9 as DATA(known as MOSI) and 10 as CLK( or SCK). But the [datasheet](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168) for my microcontroller(328) shows that pin 11 is MOSI and 13 is CLK.

Obviously..it works. So I think the program provided by the adafruit(that I used-Adafruit_SSD1306) took care of MOSI and generated the clock impulses on pin 10.etc. . But then what are those pins on the board and why are called like that? I mean it seems to me that everyone can just use other pins for MOSI/CLK(at least).What is their purpose?

Question #2: What does DC (or D/C) means?

```
#define OLED_MOSI   9
#define OLED_CLK   10
#define OLED_DC    11
#define OLED_CS    12
#define OLED_RESET 13
```

**VS**
[image]
(328<=>128)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can answer these questions by opening the library and looking "under the hood". This is the most beautiful advantage of open source projects.

Here are the links to the relevant files in the library, so I can comment on them.

- [INO example file](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/master/examples/ssd1306_128x32_spi/ssd1306_128x32_spi.ino)
- [Library header file](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/master/Adafruit_SSD1306.h)
- [Library source file](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_SSD1306/blob/master/Adafruit_SSD1306.cpp)

Ok, first of all let's have a look at the example. you can see that the constructor is called as

```
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);
```

When looking at the lines 144 and following of the source file, you can see

```
hwSPI = false;
```

Wait, this means that it is not using the hardware SPI? Sure! In the following overload, then, you can see that if you call the constructor as `Adafruit_SSD1306(int8_t DC, int8_t RST, int8_t CS)`, you will use the hwSPI.

Now, I'm not sure whether you know the difference between HW and SW implementations, so here they are. The HW implementation is a peripheral which can run "on its own" and provide the microcontroller the results (automatically send and/or receive the bytes). The SW one, on the other hand, is an emulation done by the microcontroller.

You can also see it in the example:

```
// If using software SPI (the default case):
#define OLED_MOSI   9
#define OLED_CLK   10
#define OLED_DC    11
#define OLED_CS    12
#define OLED_RESET 13
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_MOSI, OLED_CLK, OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);

/* Uncomment this block to use hardware SPI
#define OLED_DC     6
#define OLED_CS     7
#define OLED_RESET  8
Adafruit_SSD1306 display(OLED_DC, OLED_RESET, OLED_CS);
*/
```

So you can use the second part to initialize a display which will use the hardware SPI (so MISO = 12, MOSI = 11, SCK = 13). If you want to free the microcontroller in order to be able to do other tasks, use the HW peripheral.

As fot the DC pin, it is labeled "DataCommand". I think it is a pin to tell the controller whether the data shared through the SPI port is a command or it is data